# How to monitor multiple JVM using nagios?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to monitor JVM, especially for memory usage, so I can restart the services when this is required.

This has to work while having multiple JVMs running on the same machine.

Comment: I already found http://www.opennms.org/wiki/JVM_Monitoring_using_SNMP but I'm still looking for something that does not require you to spend hours configuring it.

Comment: If you need to get inside the JVM and you cannot enable JMX, then you probably need to write a Java program which use the Attach API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) instead, available in the official repos as `monit`. I've found it better suited for this sort of thing.